# Replicating the NZ function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare two fields and take the largest.  But sometimes one field will have a null value.  How would I do something like this:

=IIF(Nz(J2) > Nz(K2), J2, K2)

Comment: Excel doesn't have a Null value. What exactly does your data look like?

Comment: If by null value you mean an empty cell, then that is interpreted as a `0`

Comment: It gives me a #NAME, which I assume is because one field is empty, and it gives me a #VALUE if I just put =IF(J2 > K2, J2, K2)

Comment: Why not just use =MAX(J2,K2) In what cases does that not work?